# Prove by induction that numbers of Fibonacci of the form $F_{3n}$ are even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction, fibonacci-numbers, parity

I am not quite asking to solve this problem, but I am asking what they are asking me. This is the problem:

> The Fibonacci numbers $F_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are defined by $F_0
>  = 0$, $F_1 = 1$, and $F_n = F_{n−2} + F_{n−1}$ for $n \geq 2$. Prove (by induction) that the numbers $F_{3n}$ are even for any $n \in
>  \mathbb{N}$.

We all know what the Fibonacci numbers are, and I also know in general how proofs by induction work: assume for $n$ case, prove by $n + 1$ case. Very nice!

My problem is: what the heck are they asking me? What do you think they mean by $F_{3n}$? Are they maybe asking us to prove for the cases $3n$? For example, instead of for $n=1$ we prove for $n=3$, instead of $2$ we have $6$, and so on?

So, if my reasonings are correct, for example, the base case would be $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ as usual, but we then use the new formula $F_{3n}$.

Thus we would have to show $F_{3*0}=F_{0} = 0$ and $F_{3*1} = F_{3} = (F_{2} = 1 + F_{1} = 1) = 2$.

Well, we have show that they are even, so they are of the form $F_n = 2k$.

What exactly am I suppose to do?

Comment: Yes it means show $F_3$ is even, $F_6$ is even, $F_9$ is even, $F_{12}$ is even, etc...

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669461/proof-by-induction-involving-fibonacci-numbers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A proof by induction could go more or less like this.

$F_1=1$, $F_2=1$, and $F_3=2$. So, $F_{3\cdot1}=2$ is even.

Assume that $F_{3n}$ is even.

Now, $F_{3n+3}=F_{3n+2}+F_{3n+1}=F_{3n+1}+F_{3n}+F_{3n+1}=2F_{3n+1}+F_{3n}$.

Since $F_{3n}$ is even and $2F_{3n+1}$ is also even we get $F_{3(n+1)}=F_{3n+3}$ is even because it is the sum of these two even numbers.

Comment: @Rinzler $3n+3-1=3n+2$.

Comment: @Rinzler Think about it instead of exclaiming so much. Read the whole proof.

Comment: @Rinzler $F_{12}=F_{11}+F_{10}=F_{10}+F_9+F_{10}=2F_{10}+F_9$. $2F_{10}$ is even because it has a $2$ in front, and $F_9$ is even because it is the previous term that we know is even.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in modulo 2. In this case every Fibbonaci number is 1 or 0.

Since in modulo 2 (1+1=0):
So $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, $F_2=1$, $F_3=0$,...

We know that some even Fibonacci number exists. By the Well Ordering Principle, every non-empty subset of the positive integers has a least element. Let $F_k$ be the smallest even Fibonacci number greater than zero.

Then $F_k=0$ for some $k$. Since it is the least even Fibonacci, $F_{k-1}$=1.

Given the above and by definition of the Fibonacci numbers, $F_{k+1}=1, F_{k+2}=1,$ and  $F_{k+3}=0$, and is therefor even.

We have thus proven that if $F_k=0, k>0$, then $F_{k+3}=0$. This provides the induction step for all $F_{3n}$.